# How do I separate a data set on a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy

I'm very new to python but am interested in learning a new technique whereby I can identify different data points in a scatter plot with different markers according to where they fall in the scatter plot.

My specific example is much to this: http://www.astroml.org/examples/datasets/plot_sdss_line_ratios.html

I have a BPT plot and want to split the data along the demarcation line line.

I have a data set in this format:

```
data = [[a,b,c],
        [a,b,c],
        [a,b,c]
]
```

And I also have the following for the demarcation line:

```
NII   = np.linspace(-3.0, 0.35)

def log_OIII_Hb_NII(log_NII_Ha, eps=0):
    return 1.19 + eps + 0.61 / (log_NII_Ha - eps - 0.47)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What you can do is to split the data list into two lists, according to their being in the two planes defined by the demarcation line. Once you've done that, you can decide the color (and size,...) of each set of data separately

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you have the pixel coordinates as `a, b` in your example. The column with `c`s is then something that is used to calculate whether a point belongs to one of the two groups.

Make your data first an `ndarray`:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(data)
```

Now you may create two arrays by checking which part of the data belongs to which area:

```
dataselector = log_OIII_Hb_NII(data[:,2]) > 0
```

This creates a vector of Trues and Falses which has a True whenever the data in the third column (column 2) gives a positive value from the function. The length of the vector equals to the number of rows in `data`.

Then you can plot the two data sets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# the plotting part
ax.plot(data[dataselector,0], data[dataselector,1], 'ro')
ax.plot(data[-dataselector,0], data[-dataselector,1], 'bo')
```

I.e.:

- create a list of True/False values which tells which rows of `data` belong to which group
- plot the two groups (`-dataselector` means "all the rows where there is a False in `dataselector`")

Answer (score 1):

There was not enough room in the comments section. Not too dissimilar to what @DrV wrote, but maybe more astronomically inclined:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def log_OIII_Hb_NII(log_NII_Ha, eps=0):
    return 1.19 + eps + 0.61 / (log_NII_Ha - eps - 0.47)

# Make some fake measured NII_Ha data
iternum = 100

# Ranged -2.1 to 0.4:
Measured_NII_Ha = np.array([random.random()*2.5-2.1 for i in range(iternum)])
# Ranged -1.5 to 1.5:
Measured_OIII_Hb = np.array([random.random()*3-1.5 for i in range(iternum)])

# For our measured x-value, what is our cut-off value
Measured_Predicted_OIII_Hb = log_OIII_Hb_NII(Measured_NII_Ha)

# Now compare the cut-off line to the measured emission line fluxes
# by using numpy True/False arrays
#
# i.e., x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
# >> index = x >= 3
# >> print(index)
# >> numpy.array([False, False, True, True])
# >> print(x[index])
# >> numpy.array([3,4])

Above_Predicted_Red_Index = Measured_OIII_Hb > Measured_Predicted_OIII_Hb
Below_Predicted_Blue_Index = Measured_OIII_Hb < Measured_Predicted_OIII_Hb
# Alternatively, you can invert Above_Predicted_Red_Index



# Make the cut-off line for a range of values for plotting it as
# a continuous line
Predicted_NII_Ha = np.linspace(-3.0, 0.35)
Predicted_log_OIII_Hb_NII = log_OIII_Hb_NII(Predicted_NII_Ha)

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot the modelled cut-off line
ax.plot(Predicted_NII_Ha, Predicted_log_OIII_Hb_NII, color="black", lw=2)

# Plot the data for a given colour
ax.errorbar(Measured_NII_Ha[Above_Predicted_Red_Index], Measured_OIII_Hb[Above_Predicted_Red_Index], fmt="o", color="red")
ax.errorbar(Measured_NII_Ha[Below_Predicted_Blue_Index], Measured_OIII_Hb[Below_Predicted_Blue_Index], fmt="o", color="blue")

# Make it aesthetically pleasing
ax.set_ylabel(r"$\rm \log([OIII]/H\beta)$")
ax.set_xlabel(r"$\rm \log([NII]/H\alpha)$")

plt.show()
```

[image: plot of example code]